# Optimize ReplaceDocumentAsync with property check in CosmosDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am using DocumentDb and would like to replace a document only if the property of the document takes a certain value. Notice that all stored documents have this property (and the value can never be empty).
The only way I found is to do this in 3 steps:

1) Read the document with `ReadDocumentAsync`

2) Check if the resource response has the property value I expect

3) If step 2 returns true then do the replace with `ReplaceDocumentAsync`, otherwise do something else

I am concerned about the additional request charge and latency as this is 2 queries to the db. Is that the only way with the current .Net SDK or is there a more clever way?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could optimize this by using a Stored Procedure that executes directly in the database. The order of operations would be the same, you would include your document as part of the payload to the SPROC but there would be no round trips or extra latency.

Comment: From https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/master/samples/code-samples/ServerSideScripts/JS/UpdateMetadata.js , it seems you query and replace, so I expect this to be the same cost in request charge. Right?

Comment: Yes, request charge would be the same. You're literally doing the same set of operations but in one request all on the server. The thing you're saving is response latency and multiple round trips. There is no way to merge the contents of documents/properties currently. It can only be done by using ReplaceDocument

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you mean by running in the database and the process? I mean,  the JS script is first written in the web app server, you then create a store procedure (using the .Net sdk in my case) which I assume is already one connection to the server where the db is found, and then the set of operations you want (read-check-replace), from which a response back to your web app and then the client. Is that correct? Thanks